# Why do batsmen in T20 matches sit close to the boundary, instead of sitting in the dressing room?

Tags: rules, cricket

Why do batsmen in T20 matches sit close to the boundary, instead of sitting in the dressing room? Is there any logic behind it? Or this is just a rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T20 as a concept was to make the cricket fast paced,as short as possible and make the game appealing to all people (something like how baseball is in US). The idea was to make each innings last only for around 90 minutes so that it attracts more people to watch the game. 
One of the ways to reduce the time taken by batsmen to occupy the crease was to make them sit near the boundary.

> The prime reason why Batsmen sit close to the boundary in the T20
>   matches is to reduce the time taken by the next batsmen to occupy the
>   crease. Also it gives flexibility to send out any batsmen according to
>   the team's current situation.

If you see, at least two three batsmen will be padded up in a T20 game all the time.

Answer (score 4):

On top of @kartshan's answer, the main reason that couple of batsmen are padded and waiting in the dug-out rather than the pavilion is that batsmen are dismissed as `timed-out` in `90 seconds` in T20 cricket instead of the 180 seconds in other forms.

Comment: Fair enough.. :)